# Set aspect ratio on 2D pgfplots plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I would like to set the *aspect ratio* of a pgfplots plots without explicitly specifying width and height (i.e., leaving them default). For 3D plots, there is `plot box ratio`; for 2D plots, I tried playing with `\axisdefaultheight`, but it just blows the thing out of proportion:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[
xmin=0.0, xmax=3.0,
ymin=0.0, ymax=1.0,
scale only axis,
width=2\axisdefaultheight
]
\addplot [red]
table {%
0 0
0.1 0.587785252292473
0.2 0.951056516295154
0.3 0.951056516295154
0.4 0.587785252292473
0.5 1.22464679914735e-16
0.6 -0.587785252292473
0.7 -0.951056516295154
0.8 -0.951056516295154
0.9 -0.587785252292473
1 -2.44929359829471e-16
1.1 0.587785252292474
1.2 0.951056516295154
1.3 0.951056516295154
1.4 0.587785252292473
1.5 3.67394039744206e-16
1.6 -0.587785252292473
1.7 -0.951056516295154
1.8 -0.951056516295154
1.9 -0.587785252292473
};
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The option `unit vector ratio` takes into account the actual axis limits, so after a bit of computation, this could be used. I'm looking for a setting on the axis lengths only, though.

Any hints?

Comment: I think you can just add `unit vector ratio = {16 3}`.

Answer (score 2):

`\axisdefaultheight` is not a length but just a macro, which is why `2\axisdefaultheight` does not work, but `2*\axisdefaultheight` works. But then it is probably the simplest option to specify both the width and height.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xmin=0.0, xmax=3.0,
ymin=0.0, ymax=1.0,
scale only axis,
height=\axisdefaultheight,
width=2*\axisdefaultheight
]
\addplot [red]
table {%
0 0
0.1 0.587785252292473
0.2 0.951056516295154
0.3 0.951056516295154
0.4 0.587785252292473
0.5 1.22464679914735e-16
0.6 -0.587785252292473
0.7 -0.951056516295154
0.8 -0.951056516295154
0.9 -0.587785252292473
1 -2.44929359829471e-16
1.1 0.587785252292474
1.2 0.951056516295154
1.3 0.951056516295154
1.4 0.587785252292473
1.5 3.67394039744206e-16
1.6 -0.587785252292473
1.7 -0.951056516295154
1.8 -0.951056516295154
1.9 -0.587785252292473
};
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]